# Can I safely change jBcrypt's algorithm identifier to y?

Tags: java, security, bcrypt, jbcrypt

Due to a vulnerability in php the algorithm prefix was changed from a to y. More detail here: http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/12/seven-ways-to-screw-up-bcrypt.html . I've checked and jbcrypt is producing `$2a$...` hashes. It seems as though it is not producing the shortened version that the article discusses. However, it could be that I just havent chanced accross the proper hash. Does jBcrypt have the same vulnerabilites as php did? If not, is it then safe to change the algorithm identifier to y?

Comment: https://github.com/jeremyh/jBCrypt/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mindrot/BCrypt.java#L662 doubt it

Comment: @guest I mean, would it be safe to change the source to use y instead of a?